# matplotlib plots download from R shiny

Tags: r, matplotlib, shiny, reticulate

I have code in python which is creating plot using matplotlib. I am saving these files in directory named www and using those plots to render in R shiny app. But now I want to insert downloader button in shiny app for downloading these plots. But I am not able to figure out how to proceed..